# How can I decode a file where each letter has been replaced with the letter 13 letters ahead of it in the alphabet?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

There's a text affected by ROT13, called `rot.txt`. ROT13 (rotate by 13 places) replaces a letter with the letter 13 letters after it in the alphabet. How do I write the command to view the actual text?

I tried:

```
cat rot.txt | tr 'A-Za-z' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m'
```

but no success

Comment: Very unusual question. In your text file what about punctuation characters like `"`, `'`, `.`, `,`, `?` and `!`, etc. Are they shifted 13 by 13 ASCII decimals lower too?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way with an example

```
echo "hello world" | tr "$(echo -n {A..Z} {a..z} | tr -d ' ')" "$(echo -n {N..Z} {A..M} {n..z} {a..m} | tr -d ' ')"
```

Output:

```
uryyb jbeyq
```

Make it a function:

```
function rot13() {    
    cat | tr "$(echo -n {A..Z} {a..z} | tr -d ' ')" "$(echo -n {N..Z} {A..M} {n..z} {a..m} | tr -d ' ')" 
}
```

Usage:

```
➜ echo "hello world" | rot13 
uryyb jbeyq
```

Comment: i need to decode a full text, not just 2 words. how do i decode .txt file? thank you for your time answering

Comment: @JenaAlissa, I updated it, so you should use `cat rot.txt | rot13`

Answer (score 5):

You can also achieve the same output by using the following piece of command:

```
tr '[a-z][A-Z]' '[n-za-m][N-ZA-M]'
```

or

```
tr '[a-zA-Z]' '[n-za-mN-ZA-M]'
```

Personally, I find this syntax a lot easier.

Comment: Wonderful! And here ROT-18 (ROT-13 for letters + ROT-5 for numbers): `tr '[a-zA-Z0-45-9]' '[n-za-mN-ZA-M5-90-4]'`

Comment: ROT-47: `tr "[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/0-9\:\;\<\=\>\?\@A-OP-Z\[\\\]\^\_\`a-z\{\|\}\~]" "[P-Z\[\\\]\^\_\`a-z\{\|\}\~\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/0-9\:\;\<\=\>\?\@A-O]"`, probably too many ` \ `, you can safely remove some of them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to decrypt is to use the same program used to encrypt the test; [ROT13](https://www.dcode.fr/rot-13-cipher):

> An offset of 13 allows the encryption to be reversible. The encryption
>   and decryption method are identical. Applying 2 consecutive
>   encryptions (2 shifts of 13) heads to find the original text.

The link also mentions that numbers can be encrypted by shifting ASCII 5 positions and punctuation characters can be encrypted by shifting ASCII 47 positions.

Answer (score 1):

Rot13 is a (very simple) algorithm to shift every character 13 places.

```
abcdefghijklmn # notice it ends in "n"
+1234567890123 # 13 places
```

That's why "a" turns to "n", "b" turns to "o", etc. 'tr' is a tool to "translate" or replace characters. So to translate them to rot13 you pass the text to translate through tr like this

```
echo "hello world" | tr 'A-Za-z0-9' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4'
# will echo "uryyb jbeyq"
```

Notice the 2nd set starts with "N", because "N" is A+13. To "un"rot13, (which is what you asked and no one answered) you just switch the sets

```
echo "uryyb jbeyq" | tr 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4' 'A-Za-z0-9' 
# will be translated back to "hello world"
```

An easy way to "store" this would be to create aliases

```
alias rot13="tr 'A-Za-z0-9' 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4'"
alias unrot13="tr 'N-ZA-Mn-za-m5-90-4' 'A-Za-z0-9'"
```

So, to finaly solve your problem you'll "unencript" your file like this

```
cat rot.txt | unrot13
```

Answer (score 0):

Vim has a ROT13 feature. You could open the file and apply `g?{motion}` such as `g?G` to ROT13 to the bottom, or `g??` to ROT13 a line.

Or you could do this from the command line by apply a normal mode (`norm`) command to the whole document (`%`) with: `vi -c "%norm g??" rot.txt`